# Django-selectable - show autocomplete options on focus

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-ui

I would like to show autocomplete options on focus. If value of the input is empty, I would like to show all options. The behavior I would like to have is equivalent of the following effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="text" type="text"></input>
        <script>
            $(
                function() {
                    $('#text').autocomplete(
                        { source: ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde'], minLength: 0 }
                    ).focus(function() { $(this).autocomplete('search'); });
                }
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I do this using Django-selectable?

Answer (score 0):

have you had a chance to read a documentation for autocomplete?

especially about [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option?

basically, you need to create a service on your end, this service will return JSON formatted data, it can be list of strings ([ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]), list of records with "label" and "value" keys ([ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]), or any other data - in this case you need to additionally write data parsing function.

for the search functionality, your service should accept "term" query parameter (e.g.: http://example.com?term=foo).

to write this in Django create a view (class based or not) that will be responding to GET requests, querying database and returning data formatted as JSON (with proper content/type header in the response)

```
class MyDict(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

def search_view(request):
    term = request.get('term')
    search = {}
    if term:
        search['name__icontain'] = term
    # we are limiting answers to not dump whole db over the ajax
    # user has a possibility to narrow search
    result = [{'label': o.name, 'value': o.name} for o in MyDict.objects.filter(**search)[:50]]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question - the question was how to show autocomplete options on focus as well as after typing, so that user doesn't have to type to get some basic options.